# Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined - progress bar

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'd like to set a progress bar in my react code:

```
class imageUpload extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      image: null,
      url: '',
      progress: 0
    }
```

I have progress in my state.

```
upload = (image) => {
    ImageTools.resize(image, {
        width: 320, // maximum width
        height: 240 // maximum height
    }, function(blob, didItResize) {

        document.getElementById('preview').src = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);

      const uploadTask = storage.ref(`images/${image.name}`).put(blob);
      uploadTask.on('state_changed', 
      (snapshot) => {
        // progrss function ....
        const progress = Math.round((snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100);
        this.setState({progress}); // Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined
      },
```

when I select an image and upload it, it is going to server, but I get this error:
`Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined`

html

```
<progress value={this.state.progress} max="100"/>
```

any ideas why?

thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I guess you need to transform your anonymous function `function(blob, didItResize){}` into an arrow function `(blob, didItResize) => {}`.

Comment: thanks for your answer! it works!

Answer (score 2):

Convert your function expression into an arrow function.

```
function(blob, didItResize) {
```

to

```
(blob, didItResize) => {
```

To keep `this` pointing to the right context.

Comment: thanks for your answer! :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use **arrow function**:

```
(blob, didItResize) => { ... }
```

instead of

```
function (blob, didItResize) { ... }
```

Comment: thanks for your answer! :)